# Cannot resize Glimpse window

Tags: glimpse

I have just installed Glimpse.MV5 and EF6 and all the plug-ins seem to working fine, however there is a problems with the UI and I cannot resize the Glimpse window (and it is very small by default). Also if I open it up in a separate window it only takes up a fraction of the window and finally I cannot re-size the panels in the Timeline tab.

Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of the pop-up window.

[image: Glimpse popup window]

Cheers Mike

Comment: Could you add a printscreen of this? What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tested this in IE10 and the latest Chrome. Exactly the same in both browsers. Not sure how to add a screenshot.

Comment: Screenshot of the popup window added.

Comment: Very difficult to actually show the issue on a screenshot, but as you can see the timeline info only takes up the top part of the screen. Also if I hover over the horizontal bar it does not change the mouse pointer and I cannot drag it up or down.

Comment: Is it the same if you look at other tabs besides timeline?

Comment: No, other tabs seem fine. I also just managed to get the Timeline tab to fill the whole window by repeatedly minimizing and maximizing the window. But that now no longer seems to work.

Comment: @MikeDymond Just to confirm, but when you said: "however there is a problems with the UI and I cannot resize the Glimpse window (and it is very small by default)" you were also taking about the Timeline tab?

Comment: @anthonyv If I'm not mistaken, there is no way to resize those 2 parts by means of the horizontal bar? At least I've never been able to do so either.

Comment: Just to confirm, Yes I was talking about the Timeline tab when I said it appeared small and cannot be resized. I am sure when I have used Glimpse in the past I could drag the horizontal bar in the middle of the Timeline tab to show more or less of the Categories info compared to the Events info.

Comment: Even if that was never the case there are still two other issues, firstly the information on the timeline tab should fill the entire window, not just the top third. And secondly you should be able to change the amount of the glimpse window shown when not viewing it in popup mode.

Comment: Raise a bug for this one. Because of the way timeline works, it has a slightly different system which governs the "perceived" height of the tab. I will need to take a look at it again to see whats going on. Raise the bug here - https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse.client/issues

Comment: OK, this is now really confusing. The issue with the popup window now seem to have disappeared. I have also found that the issue with dragging the info panel goes away in Firefox (but is present in Chrome and IE).

Answer (score 0):

You are reporting two different issues.

One is you cannot resize the Glimpse panel. By default it is 300px. I just submitted an issue to Glimpse that if the page loads with the Glimpse panel minimized, it cannot be resized. The workaround is to expand the Glimpse panel, then reload the page. Then you can resize the panel using the mouse.

Here is the issue I submitted: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/742

The second issue is the panel contents are not filling the entire size of the panel. This bug was submitted and marked as fix a while ago. See the issue report here: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/326

**UPDATE**

The Glimpse team has committed a fix for not being able to resize the panel. The fix is here: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/commit/3677494af54e59f29eb1b4539773e1d5ded1c1c5

**UPDATE**
The fix was released in version 1.8.4 on March 11, 2014. Details here: https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues?milestone=23&state=closed

Comment: @DarellNorton You are correct, there are two separate issues, both of which have been reported to Glimpse. However they are issues with the Glimpse.Client project and hence the two issues are:  
  
Glimpse panel not resizable - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Client/issues/46  
  
Glimpse Timeline not using full area - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse.Client/issues/45

Comment: @MikeDymond thanks for the links. Someone commented on the issue I submitted (742) that they would look into a fix. I also commented on your thread (46) to hopefully help them figure out the issue.